# How to prevent default pdf viewer from being changed to iBooks

Tags: pdf, preview, settings, books, defaults

Every so often the default viewer for PDF files gets changed to iBooks.  I want PDF files to be opened with Preview, and I want that setting to persist.

I know how to manually change the default back to Preview (by going to the file in Finder and then clicking Get Info > Open With > Change All).  However, at some point after I make the change, the defaults gets switched to iBooks again.  Is there a way to prevent that from happening, and lock the default PDF viewer to Preview?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167867/prevent-changing-default-app-for-some-file-extensions

Comment: Keeps happening to me, too:( I've changed the default viewer back to Preview about 100 times in the last year. MacBook Pro running 10.11.6